# store an array for a given key in java

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

i want to store my data such that i have a relation between multiple locations (where each location is a Object) with a city (a String). I am confused with data structure. 
Should I go with:

```
Map<String, List<Location>> data = new HashMap<String, List<Location>>
```

or

```
Map<String, List<Location>> data = new TreeMap<String, List<<Location>>
```

which one is best suited for my requirement. I know how Hash and Tree works in data-structure but not sure how it is implemented in Java.

If there is any better approach available then won't mind going with that.

Comment: A `Map` is the right approach. As to what is better as an implementation between `HashMap` and `TreeMap`, you could only tell by profiling your specific application. Both have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: The `TreeMap` is actually a Red-Black tree implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TreeMap uses Balanced-Binary search tree data-structure(Red-Black Tree), which uses O(log n) cost to look up, insertion and removal of data. However HashMap on the other hand poses [the following cost](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> **This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.** An instance of HashMap has two parameters that affect its performance:
>   *initial capacity* and *load factor*.
>   As a general rule, the **default load factor (.75)** offers a good
>   tradeoff between time and space costs. Higher values decrease the
>   space overhead but increase the lookup cost (reflected in most of the
>   operations of the HashMap class, including **get** and **put**). The expected
>   number of entries in the map and its load factor should be taken into
>   account when setting its initial capacity. As, when the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is **rehashed**. So to *minimize* the
>   number of rehash operations. If the initial capacity is greater than
>   the *maximum* number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash
>   operations will ever occur.

So we better ask the question:

1. Do we need the data to be kept in an order ? If yes then I think i
   should use TreeMap
2. Or We just need the mapping with key-value relation then i would use
   hashmap.

For your use case, I think the choice should be HashMap.

Comment: if i set load factor to 1 and give initial capacity making sure that rehashing never happens, what will be the impact on lookup cost? Will it be unaffected or will it degrade?

Comment: well that will decreases the space overhead but will increase the look up cost making it too slow

Comment: @S4beR, For better understanding, how really load factor affect hashing performance, I think you might want to check [this article first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash map if you need very fast (constant) operations (look-up,add,remove) and don't care about ordered iteration of the map keys. Use a tree map if you want fast (logarithmic) operations but also want to iterate the map keys in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). Which implementation that was said in the comment section and by @Justing above. This is pretty useful as doing it manually as you mentioned has some shortcomings (you need to check if the list for a key exists etc.).